# function with loop in r

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am having some trouble getting the following function to work. This is just a simplification of the function I have to use.

Data example:

```
x = c(1628.584,2071.944,3365.916, 6450.724)
n = length(x)
r = seq(0.1,0.5,by=0.1)
q = seq(0,2,by=1)
```

Then I write a function that has to be used in the next function:

```
 gh <- function(r,q){
    ifelse(r>0 & p>1, r*p,
           ifelse(r>0 & p==1, q+1-r, NA))
  }
```

What I want the next function to do is:

```
# p=1
# d <- (log(x[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(r,q,gh))^2
# p=2
# f <- (log(x[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(r,q,gh))^2
# p=3 
# g <- (log(x[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(r,q,gh))^2
# p=4
# k <- (log(x[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(r,q,gh))^2
#
# z <- d+f+g+k
```

Therefore, I write:

```
ws <- function(r,q){
  we=0
  for(p in seq(from=1,to=4, by=1)){
    we= we+ (log(x[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(r,q,gh))^2
  }
  return(we)
}

o <-ws(r,q)
```

But then I get the error:

```
Error in ifelse(r > 0 & p > 1, r * p, ifelse(r > 0 & p == 1, q + 1 - r,  : 
                                                 object 'p' not found
```

This I am having trouble understanding, because I am looping over "p" ?

Comment: the problem is that `p` is not defined inside `gh` function

Comment: for(p in seq(from=1,to=4, by=1)) can be written as for (p in 1:4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?outer`:

> outer(X, Y, FUN = "*", ...)
>
> ...   optional arguments to be passed to

So , you can add a parameter p to your function :

```
gh <- function(r,q,p){
  ifelse(r>0 & p>1, r*p,
         ifelse(r>0 & p==1, q+1-r, NA))
}
```

Then you call it using `...` argument:

```
outer(r,q,gh,p=1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.9  1.9  2.9
[2,]  0.8  1.8  2.8
[3,]  0.7  1.7  2.7
[4,]  0.6  1.6  2.6
[5,]  0.5  1.5  2.5
```

In your loop you call it:

```
 outer(r,q,gh,p=p)
```

That's said I am pretty sure that you do not need to use `for` here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I still having a little trouble. If I put in what you wrote I get the following error:  Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : unused argument (p = 1) I am still new to R, could this be done with an apply easier?

Comment: @Mathy you should start a new R session I think.